# Getting specific files from server

Tags: file, bash, shell, terminal

Using Terminal and Shell/Bash commands is there a way to retrive specific files from a web directory? I.e.

Directory: www.site.com/samples/

copy all files ending in ".h" into a folder

The folder contains text files, and other files associated that are of no use.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of achieving this recursively:
1. using find

1.1 making directorys using find -p to create recursive folders without errors

```
cd path;
mkdir backup
find www.site.com/samples/ -type d -exec mkdir -p {} backup/{} \;
```

1.2 finding specific files and copying to backup folder -p to perserve permissions

```
find www.site.com/samples/ -name \*.h -exec   cp -p {} backup/{} \;
```

1. Using tar well actually for reverse type of work i.e. to exclude specific files which the part of the question related to text files matches this answer more:
   You can have as many excludes as you liked added on

   ```
   tar --exclude=*.txt --exclude=*.filetype2 --exclude=*.filetype3 -cvzf site-backup.tar.gz www.site.com
   mv www.site.com www.site.com.1
   tar -xvzf site-backup.tar.gz
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry it's taken me so long to update this.. I get a file cannot be found, even though, I'm taking samples from: http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~dwagn/aiproj/ I don't want to download each one individually! Any ideas?

Comment: it sounds like remote web content rather than local files which is what advice was given for: you could try:  wget -m http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~dwagn/aiproj/  --- once done cd www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~dwagn/aiproj and all files from site is in local folder

Comment: I do not have access to the server, would this be a problem?

Comment: well in that case you would need to get the files as if you were a remote user, there are various commands/utilities you can use - the above comment highlighted wget -m url which does a mirror of site and should work fine.                                             wget -m cs.dartmouth.edu/~dwagn/aiproj

Answer (score 1):

```
cp -aiv /www.site.com/samples/*.h /somefolder/
```

http://linux.die.net/man/1/cp

Answer (score 1):

You can use the wget for that, but if there are no links to that files. I.e. they exist, but they are not referenced from any html page, then bruteforce is the only option.